# xbuild throws an error dont know how to handle globalsection

Tags: linux, vb.net, mono, xbuild

My app in (perfectly working on windows 10 64bit on .NET 4.6) does not compile on linux. I followed a guide that states to run `xbuild /p:VbcToolExe=vbnc.exe NAME.sln`

That gave this error:

`home/icbosk/Desktop/WindowsApp1/watch.sln:  warning : Don't know how to handle GlobalSection ExtensibilityGlobals, Ignoring.`

Then it fails.

I don't know how to do make this work on linux.

Here is the full output with diagnostics:

https://pastebin.com/WB5p9Zsi

Comment: use msbuild, xbuild is deprecated

Comment: what? isnt xbuild same as msbuild?

Comment: xbuild was the opensource equivalent to msbuild, but now that msbuild has been opensourced, xbuild is deprecated

Comment: Neither xbuild nor vbnc should be used (both obsolete). Now it is MSBuild (`msbuild`) and Roslyn (`vbc`) from Microsoft. Whatever guide you were reading is out-of-date.